# Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$winner_id

Tags: php, laravel

I have a draw system on my site. There are 2 draws in the database now, but for some reason, only the last created draw is displayed on the draw page. My code is:

```
public function raffling()
{
    parent::setTitle('Items raffling | ');
    $green_ticket = \DB::table('users')->where('id', $this->user->id)->value('green_ticket');

    $kolvo=\DB::table('giveaway_items')->where('status',0)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->count();
    $giveaway = Giveaway::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
    $giveaway_users = \DB::table('giveaway_users')
        ->where('giveaway_id', $giveaway->id)
        ->join('users', 'giveaway_users.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->get();
    $giveAway = Giveaway::where('winner_id', '!=', 'NULL')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->first();
    $user = User::find($giveAway->winner_id);
    $username = $user->username;
    $userava = $user->avatar;
    $usersteamid = $user->steamid64;


    return view('pages.raffling', compact('kolvo', 'giveaway', 'giveaway_users', 'giveAway', 'user', 'username',
                                         'userava', 'usersteamid', 'green_ticket'));

}
```

I tried make changes at `$giveaway = Giveaway::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();` and instead of `first()` use `take(2)`, but i received error `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$winner_id`. And the same error appears if I add `take(2)` to the line `$giveAway = Giveaway::where('winner_id', '!=', 'NULL')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->first();` instead of `first()`.

Where is my problem, how i can fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have used `first()` method means only one records retrieve.

Now as you said you want two records from the database. There are two methods available here.

**1) take()**

```
$giveaway = Giveaway::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(2)->get();
```

**2) limit()**

```
$giveaway = Giveaway::orderBy('id', 'desc')->limit(2)->get();
```

*Your problem occurs because you have not used the `get()` method.

Answer (score 1):

`take()` is a method that is available on collections not the query builder. You need to get a collection from the query builder first and then use the method on that.

```
$giveAway = Giveaway::where('winner_id', '!=', 'NULL')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->get()
    ->take(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

use `take(2)`

```
$giveaway = Giveaway::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->take(2)->get();
```