# laravel Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id

Tags: php, laravel

The site has a page with draws. By default, the last draws show via `$giveaway = Giveaway::orderBy('id', 'desc')->where('status', 0)->first();`, all was fine. When i try to add another draw, the previous one is no longer displayed and the newest draw is displayed.

I try to change `$giveaway` (as i explain at first line) like this:

`$giveaway = Giveaway::orderBy('id', 'desc')->where('status', 0)->take(2)->get();`

And i received error `PagesController.php line 385: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id`, 385 line it's: `->where('giveaway_id', $giveaway->id)`

My code:

```
public function raffling()
{
    parent::setTitle('Items raffling | ');
    $green_ticket = \DB::table('users')->where('id', $this->user->id)->value('green_ticket');
    $userid = htmlspecialchars_decode($this->user->id);
    $user = User::where('id', $userid)->first();
    $kolvo=\DB::table('giveaway_items')->where('status',0)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->count();
    $giveaway = Giveaway::orderBy('id', 'desc')->where('status', 0)->take(2)->get();
    $giveaway_users = \DB::table('giveaway_users')
        ->where('giveaway_id', $giveaway->id)
        ->join('users', 'giveaway_users.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->get();
    $giveAway = Giveaway::where('winner_id', '!=', 'NULL')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->first();
    $user = User::find($giveAway->winner_id);
    $username = $user->username;
    $userava = $user->avatar;
    $usersteamid = $user->steamid64;

    $is_enter = \DB::table('giveaway_users')->where('giveaway_id', $giveaway->id)->where('user_id', $userid)->count();

    return view('pages.raffling', compact('kolvo', 'giveaway', 'giveaway_users', 'giveAway', 'user', 'username', 'userava', 
    'usersteamid', 'green_ticket', 'is_enter'));

}
```

`var_dump($giveaway)` with `->first()` at variable say me this:

```
object(App\Giveaway)#586 (23) { ["table":protected]=> string(8) "giveaway" ["fillable":protected]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(8) "max_user" [1]=> string(5) "items" [2]=> string(9) "winner_id" [3]=> string(13) "green_tickets" [4]=> string(5) "price" } ["connection":protected]=> NULL ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["timestamps"]=> bool(true) ["attributes":protected]=> array(12) { ["id"]=> int(103) ["max_user"]=> int(2) ["items"]=> string(472) "[{"id":1025,"assetid":"18251557509","market_hash_name":"Test","classid":"-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KW1Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXK9QlSPcU_phVWSVXvTO2j0IDeXFN_IB1ovbOrLDhp3v7HYylD4OOhkYGbmPm7PrTfnW5I1854hO7-_IH4h0agqh8DJDyiZNnLbAE8M13Q-Ae4wrq7g5Pq7cufnCRm7nZ3tCyPlhSyhx1IabZrjPKaQVqAR_se2_6rU3g","price":31.86,"steamid":"1","type":"card","bot":"1","status":0,"created_at":"2020-03-03 17:36:32","updated_at":"2020-03-14 17:41:25","is_withdraw":0,"is_raffling":0}]" ["finished_at"]=> NULL ["winner_id"]=> NULL ["status"]=> int(0) ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2020-03-18 21:08:52" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2020-03-18 21:08:52" ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["green_tickets"]=> int(2) ["price"]=> float(31.86) ["classid"]=> string(0) "" } ["original":protected]=> array(12) { ["id"]=> int(103) ["max_user"]=> int(2) ["items"]=> string(472) "[{"id":1025,"assetid":"18251557509","market_hash_name":"Test","classid":"-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KW1Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXK9QlSPcU_phVWSVXvTO2j0IDeXFN_IB1ovbOrLDhp3v7HYylD4OOhkYGbmPm7PrTfnW5I1854hO7-_IH4h0agqh8DJDyiZNnLbAE8M13Q-Ae4wrq7g5Pq7cufnCRm7nZ3tCyPlhSyhx1IabZrjPKaQVqAR_se2_6rU3g","price":31.86,"steamid":"1","type":"card","bot":"1","status":0,"created_at":"2020-03-03 17:36:32","updated_at":"2020-03-14 17:41:25","is_withdraw":0,"is_raffling":0}]" ["finished_at"]=> NULL ["winner_id"]=> NULL ["status"]=> int(0) ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2020-03-18 21:08:52" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2020-03-18 21:08:52" ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["green_tickets"]=> int(2) ["price"]=> float(31.86) ["classid"]=> string(0) "" } ["relations":protected]=> array(0) { } ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { } ["visible":protected]=> array(0) { } ["appends":protected]=> array(0) { } ["guarded":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "*" } ["dates":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dateFormat":protected]=> NULL ["casts":protected]=> array(0) { } ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { } ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { } ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["morphClass":protected]=> NULL ["exists"]=> bool(true) ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=> bool(false) }
```

Also i try change `$giveaway->id` to `$giveaway[0]->id`, but nothing changed.

And in the blade all show by `@foreach(json_decode($giveaway->items) as $item)`

Where is my problem? How i can fix this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$winner\_id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60737979/undefined-property-illuminate-database-eloquent-builderwinner-id)

Comment: Side Note: it literally is the same question and the answer to it will likely be the same

Comment: yes, this answer to my question, it solved that problem, but that answer does not solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

```php
$giveaway = Giveaway::orderBy('id', 'desc')->where('status', 0)->take(2)->get();
```

This line take two records from Giveaway,

so you need to use `pluck` to get two `id` from `$giveaway`, then use `whereIn` for filtering the result:

```php
$giveaway_users = \DB::table('giveaway_users')
                    ->whereIn('giveaway_id', $giveaway->pluck('id'))
```